# How to check UIView is empty or not

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, swift2

I have multiple UIView, then after add and remove button on UIView in last want check my view is empty or not.

[image]

above image 3rd view is empty how to check programmatically
this view is empty or not.

Comment: How is "UIView is empty"?

Comment: If you're in a situation where you need to check whether a view has sub views or not, you probably have other core problems with your code's design. Why aren't you sure what's going on through another means? For example, a configuration that's set or class controlling it? Or perhaps, an IBOutlet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
extension UIView {
    var isViewEmpty : Bool {
        return  self.subviews.count == 0 ;
    }
}
```

**Paste extension code outside of the viewController class.**

After removing button from view, every time check for `isViewEmpty` as below,

```
//if you don't have the object of view, you can get view as below,
let view = bottonToRemove.superview;//this will give you obejct for check

//your code to remove button from the view

if view.isViewEmpty {
     //implement your logic for if view is empty
}else{
    //view not empty
    //do you stuff
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check the amount of subviews in that specific view:

```
if([theView.subviews count] == 0) {
    // View does not contain subviews
}
```

If you have multiple UIViews inside a parent view and you wish to figure out which views are empty, then loop over the parent subviews and check each if empty or not:

```
for(UIView * view in parentView.subviews) {
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]] && [view.subviews count] == 0) {
        // We found an empty UIView... 
        // Can you identify this view?
        // If you need to do something with it, do it here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIView has a property subViews. This will return you an array of all subViews. If the array is null or has count zero then there is no subview in it.

Answer (score -1):

i think as per your requirement you need check there is any button in view or not you can try

```
BOOL isEmpty = true;
for (UIButton *btn in viewTest.subviews) {
    if ([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        isEmpty = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (isEmpty == false) {
    // there is button in view
}
else
{
// there no button in view
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Seems like you are checking on the UINavigationBar,

```
for (UIView *view in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {

if(view)
  //Do your thing
}
```

Comment: Please do share your discontent and concerns before downvoting answers.

Comment: Kindly change UINavigationbar to UIView object , it should be your UIView's object. as Iqbal mentioned it as UIView.

Comment: @ShaluRaj - Agree with the HarshIT comment. As per the question, that is related to the view with no subviews and not subviews of navigationBar.